problem adding and moving QGraphicsScene elements
I am building an application for my end-of-study project, in this application the first window contains keywords, the second contains file names, the third is a graphical workspace and the last is a console.
The problem I have is that I can't do a drag and drop to override the elements of the first two windows in the graphic space, so I tried by double clicking; while I found a solution the elements appear in space but I cannot move or select them.
So, my question is: how to deal with QGraphicsScene?
This is the main class:
import sys
import json
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QVBoxLayout, QSplitter, QWidget, QListWidget, QTextEdit, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from CustomWidget import CustomWidget 

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Application PyQt5")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)


        self.current_x = 0
        self.current_y = 0

        self.keywords = []  
        self.scripts = []   

        self.view1 = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene1 = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view1.setScene(self.scene1)

        self.keywordList = QListWidget()
        self.fileListe = QListWidget()
        self.console = QTextEdit()

        top_layout = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        top_layout.addWidget(self.keywordList)
        top_layout.addWidget(self.view1)


        bottom_layout = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        bottom_layout.addWidget(self.fileListe)
        bottom_layout.addWidget(self.console)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(top_layout, stretch=3)
        layout.addWidget(bottom_layout, stretch=1)

        self.keywordList.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.fileListe.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.view1.setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, self.view1.width(), self.view1.height()))
        self.view1.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.custom_widget = CustomWidget(self.view1)
        
        central_widget = CustomWidget(self.view1)
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        central_widget.view1 = self.view1  
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.load_data()

        self.keywordList.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.add_label_to_scene)
        self.fileListe.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.add_label_to_scene)

    def load_data(self):
        self.keywordList.clear()
        self.fileListe.clear()
        with open('keywords.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            self.keywords = data['keywords']
            self.scripts = data['script']
        for keyword_data in self.keywords:
            keyword = keyword_data['keyword']
            self.keywordList.addItem(keyword)
        for script_data in self.scripts:
            file_name = script_data['file_name']
            self.fileListe.addItem(file_name)

    def add_label_to_scene(self, item):
        text = item.text()
        label = QLabel(text)
        label.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;")
        proxy = self.view1.scene().addWidget(label)
        self.custom_widget.enable_draggable(proxy)
        proxy.setPos(self.current_x, self.current_y)
        self.current_x += 50
        self.current_y += 50

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

And this is the CustomWidget class:
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, view1): 
        super().__init__()
        self.view1 = view1  
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        self.painter.drawRect(self.rect())
    

    def enable_draggable(self, item):
        item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("Left mouse button pressed.")
        self.checkItemsUnderMouse(event.pos())
        event.accept()

    def checkItemsUnderMouse(self, pos):
        print("Element clicked:")
        for item in self.view1.scene().items():
            if isinstance(item, QGraphicsProxyWidget):
                widget = item.widget()
                if isinstance(widget, QLabel):
                    print("Text:", widget.text())
                    print("Position:", item.pos())

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.setAccepted(True)

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()




I tried to change all the windows to QGraphicsScene but it didn't work.


Your intuition is not completely off, but it's clear that you're missing some elementary concepts and you're therefore trying to find out your way by "randomly" putting together code you've found somewhere. One clear example is your attempt to create a QPainter in the __init__ and call drawRect(), which is wrong from any possible point of view (try to run that code from a terminal or prompt, and you'll see some insightful error messages). My suggestion is to be patient and not try to get your final purpose at this time, but gradually learn the basics of what you want and need to use.

First of all, read all the QPainter documentation (including all pages linked in it), then do some experimenting with it, using very basic shape primitives; then do the same with QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene and the basic items they provide. You cannot expect to learn how they work without understanding their basics. Take your time, learning is never about time, but about experience (no matter what nowadays irresponsible "tutorial providers" may want you to believe).
